# Styling html object with append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to style a html object with append ?

```
<div id="mini-canvas-grid" class="row"></div>

const miniCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
miniCanvas.setAttribute("id", 'mini-canvas'+ somerandomid);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("width", 400);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("height", 200);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("style", 'border: 2px solid #3F9CE8; margin-bottom:5px');
$('#mini-canvas-grid').append('<div>'+miniCanvas'+<p>Name</p></div>')
```

I'm getting [object HTMLCanvasElement] Name in the browser

Answer (score 2):

`miniCanvas` is an element, but you're treating it as a string here:

```
'<div>'+miniCanvas'+<p>Name</p></div>'
```

(Not to mention the syntax error, which is either causing errors in your code or you've modified the code in the question.)

One approach would be to create the wrapping `div` element and append it to that.  Something like this:

```
let div = $('<div/>');
div.append(miniCanvas);
div.append('<p>Name</p>');
$('#mini-canvas-grid').append(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```
$('#mini-canvas-grid').append('<div>'+miniCanvas.outerHTML+'<p>Name</p></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
somerandomid = "somerandomid"
const miniCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
miniCanvas.setAttribute("id", 'mini-canvas-' + somerandomid);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("width", 400);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("height", 200);
miniCanvas.setAttribute("style", 'border: 2px solid #3F9CE8; margin-bottom:5px');
div = document.createElement('div')
p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerHTML = "Name"
div.appendChild(miniCanvas)
div.appendChild(p)
console.log(div.innerHTML)
document.getElementById('mini-canvas-grid').append(miniCanvas)
```

```html
<div id="mini-canvas-grid" class="row"></div>
```